# A metric space is homeomorphic to a subspace of a cube $I^{X}$. Separation of points and closed sets proof question.

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to see if there is a flaw in my proof for the separation of points and closed sets.

**Prove:  Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.  Then it is homeomorphic to a subspace of the cube $I^{X}$.**

Let $f_a(x) = d(x,a)$ map $(X,d)$ into $[0,1]$ by $f_a(x) = d(x,a)$.  Then since I'm trying to show the family of functions $\{f_a\}$ separates points and closed sets, I need to show that $f_a(x) \notin cl(f_a(A))$ for some $a \in X$.

So let $x \in X$ be arbitrary and $A \subseteq X$ such that $x \notin A$.

Then $x \in X \backslash A$, so there exists an open ball $B_r(a) = \{x: x \in X \backslash A \land d(x, a) < r\}$ about $a$.

Since $A$ is closed, there exists a closed ball $C_r(a) = \{x: x \in A \land d(x, a) \ge r \}$ about $a$ that's disjoint fron $B_r(a)$.

Since $C_r(a)$ is closed, $cl(C_r(a))$ = $C_r(a)$.

So $B_r(a) \cap C_r(a) = \emptyset \Rightarrow d(x,a) \notin cl(d(A,a)) \Rightarrow f_a(x) \notin cl(f_a(A))$.

Comment: $C_r(a)$ is not a closed ball around $a$.

Comment: So if I just say it is a closed set that contains $A$ which is disjoint from the open ball why does this not work?

Comment: Do you define $a$ somewhere? You start with $x$ and $A$, but what is your choice for $a$?

Comment: $a$ is an element of $X$, so the family $f_a$ is a family of functions with the metric defined with respect to each $a$.

Comment: True, but that means you have to pick $a$, which I don't think you do.